# Editing this Script to my needs

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

I want to use this Script to build a custom Wordlist.
[Wordlist Script](https://github.com/lukapusic/wordlist-creator/blob/master/wordlist.sh)

This Script will build a Wordlist with only loweralpha Chars. But i want lower/upper Chars and Numbers.
The Output should be like this example:

```
test
123test
test123
Test
123Test
Test123
```

I dont know how to change it. I would be really happy if you could help me out with this. 
I tried some tutorials for grep and regex but i dont understand anything.

Comment: are you trying to convert lowercase words to camelCase basically?

Comment: No. This Script scrapes Websites for Words filtered by grep and regex. The current configuration converts uppercase chars to lowercase, but i want the Words in "original" as they are on the Website.

Comment: Please include your script directly in your question. It may become unavailable or you will just commit a new version and your question won't make a sense anymore.

Comment: Remove `| tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line 18 of the script

```
page=`grep '' -R "./temp/" | sed -e :a -e 's/<[^>]*>//g;/</N;//ba' | tr " " "\n" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sed -e '/[^a-zA-Z]/d' -e '/^.\{9,25\}$/!d' | sort -u`;
```

With this:

```
page=`grep '' -R "./temp/" | sed -e :a -e 's/<[^>]*>//g;/</N;//ba' | tr " " "\n" | sort -u`;
```

If you have a look at it, you can see how it

1. replaces `" "` with `"\n"`,
2. changes cases
3. filters by length
4. sorts

You can remove bits from that pipe chain and see how the output changes

Answer (score 0):

delete this bit from the script:

```
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' |
```

that will leave case alone.

there's also a bit in `wordlist.sh` that only selects words from 9 to 25 characters which you could delete, or change if you prefer a different range:

```
`sed -e '/[^a-zA-Z]/d' -e '/^.\{9,25\}$/!d' |`
```

or you could try a simpler strategy: download and install w3m, a command-line web browser, and replace the complicated line in `wordlist.sh` with this:

```
page=`grep '' -R "./temp/" | w3m -dump wikipedia.org | grep -o '\w\+' | sort -u`
```

the `grep` is (a weird) way to get all the text from the html files, then `w3m -dump` gets rid of all the html tags and other non-display stuff, and `grep -o '\w\+'` matches any word.